# Why does my vote to delete an answer not appear after being deleted from reviewers?

Tags: support, bug, low-quality-posts, vote-to-delete

**Edit:**

Seeing that this isn't a priority for the devs, my (new/additional) question now is:

- Why should I vote to delete a post if it's not going to count and I blow a vote for nothing?

This issue is still happening and I don't see why I should bother voting to delete anything other than not being related to reviewers deleting them instead.

Is there a specific reason why this **bug** hasn't been dealt with and fixed?  It's been rather a while now.

---

*Original post*:

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879975/1415724) (now deleted, 10k+):

Being:

> I hope that this tutorial for beginners will help you: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

For this question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879958/how-to-use-nginx

I first casted a downvote then a vote to delete it where I also flagged it as being of "very low quality" and was fit as a comment; not to mention a link only.

Why hasn't my name appeared under the persons who voted to delete the answer and only the ones [from the reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17702411)?

[image]

This has happened (to me) a few times before and am curious why this is?

Review link:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17702411

If there is a duplicate post for this, then I apologize since I did not find a related question for this.

Note: The question may end up getting deleted which won't be accessible by members <10k.

Screenshot of the question/answer and the first vote to delete it was mine.

[image]

Comment: Does the delete vote still show up in your history?

Comment: I don't see any vote to delete on the answer, you voted to delete the *question*. You did flag the answer as VLQ.

Comment: *But he didn't ask any question so I can't answer* ... priceless ...

Comment: Looks like DeleteOverflow to me.  Normally 3 delete votes are enough to destroy such a post.  Not actually sure how many it can list, this doesn't happen very often.

Comment: @Rob Yes it does and [here's the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879958/how-to-use-nginx/46879975#46879975).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then how do you explain [it being in my history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879958/how-to-use-nginx/46879975#46879975). Would you like me to take a screenshot of my delete history?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I didn't say you didn't vote to delete, just that I don't see the vote on the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: what I do see is that there were 2 delete votes, total, I just I can't see who cast them. Since 3 recommendations plus 1 delete vote from the review queue indeed triggers a deletion, this looks like a potential bug in the review queue handling.

Comment: I can assure you @MartijnPieters  that I voted to delete the answer and this isn't the first time this happens.

Comment: @HansPassant: there were only 2 delete votes. The review queue also hand 3 **recommendations**. 4 recommendations would also cause a delete, I'm assuming here that the 1 actual delete vote in the queue completed the set with the 3 recommendations. At which point Fred's delete vote should really also have counted.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn Just doing a follow-up. About that potential bug; do you know if this has been fixed? There hasn't been any further activity. Or, is the answer posted by Machavity the only answer there is for the moment? Edit: Should the post be retagged also as a potential bug?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: could be classified as a bug I guess, yes. I don't think anything has been done to fix this, no.

Comment: @GhostlyMartijn Thanks, I added the "bug" tag. We'll see what happens.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Update: I take it that the team may not find it to be important to fix the bug. I voted to delete 2 more posts where they were deleted but my vote to delete them was not part of them. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47090160/1415724) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47088031/1415724). Just wondering if anything is planned on fixing it (or not).

Comment: @Fred-ii-: there is no point in pinging me on that though. I don't know what has priority and what doesn't, we have no access to what is planned to be fixed. That info is usually not shared, either it will be fixed, or it won't be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok thanks. I didn't know if you were part of it or not. I'll just leave the question as it is then. I added the "bug" tag for it. Time will tell I guess.

Answer (score 13):

It's something that's been around for a while (I could have sworn I saw this discussed elsewhere but I can't find it either). The first deletion took place because of a review. So that becomes the *de facto* reason it was deleted, *even if other delete votes were cast*. The [question timeline shows this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46879958/timeline#answer_46879975)

[image]

That first timestamp? I think that's your delete vote but it could be the flag time. The second one corresponds to the time the review was completed. The review simply supercedes other deletion reasons.

Comment: Yeah this has definitely come up before. Think at the time I even tried undeleting and redeleting such a post (a couple of times IIRC) and it still ended up being shown as deleted from review.

Comment: How can I see this timeline format when I'm navigating from the question? (sorry if it's a basic question, I haven't seen this before)

Comment: You don't AFAIK. Just have to know it's there

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ There's a userscript for that: https://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links/4238#4238

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ manual version: look at question URL, replace "questions" with "posts", replace "long-title-of-the-question" with "timeline", and Bob's your uncle. Answer timeline links are therein.